`CreateWindowEx` Appears to be Returning Incorrectly Aligned Pointer Win32
I have the following code in a Win32 project written in C:
const HWND window = CreateWindowExW(...);

static_assert(alignof *window == alignof (int)); // 1. Always true

assert((uintptr_t) window % alignof (int) == 0); // 2. *FALSE* in general

assert((uintptr_t) window % alignof (short) == 0); // 3. Always true, at least in my testing

<windef.h> includes the following code, which corroborates statement 1:
typedef struct HWND__ { // NOTE: This code is abridged for simplicity
    int unused;
} *HWND;

Statements 1. and 2. are in inherent contradition. Statement 3. leads me to believe that this behavior is a holdover of the Win16 API, where sizeof (int) == 2.
Why is this happening?
Is this a bug in the Win32 API?

No. This is a bug sitting in your chair. :-) An HWND is not a pointer. It's an opaque data structure that is not documented (and is not intended to be). It's not intended to be considered as or used as a pointer. It's intended to be used as an HWND that is returned from or supplied to functions where it is documented to be used, and nothing else.

@KenWhite I wish the bug was on my side. Unfortunately for my application, the "bug" appears to be in a code translator (from C to Zig) that interprets HWND as an aligned pointer (which is what led me to look in the source code) and consequently throws an error in debug mode 50% of the time. I'm not quite sure how to get around this other than by modifying the generate .zig file. :-(

@WilliamRyman The alignment of a pointer is not guaranteed to be the same as the alignment of the thing it points at. The code is assuming something it should not be assuming.

@RemyLebeau Where do I make that assumption?

the "bug" appears to be in a code translator (from C to Zig) that interprets HWND as an aligned pointer - Then you should be talking to whoever wrote or maintains that translator so that they can fix their mistake. That doesn't make it a bug with Win32, though. MS has clearly documented the fact that an HWND is not intended to be considered anything other than an internal structure since Windows was introduced, so any misuse of it has nothing to do with them.

@KenWhite I wasn't arguing with you. But TBF, Window's implementation does appear to be incorrect regardless. Semantically speaking, pointers do have alignment. If they wanted to implement HWND as an "alignmentless" opaque pointer, why didn't they just do this: typedef struct { char unused; } *HWND;? It would be impossible for the mantainer of the translator to fix this because this is a semantic error on Window's side; they abused the meaning of a pointer erroneously.

@RemyLebeau Would it be possible for you to point out the assumption directly? I'm not sure whether I should interpret your statement as saying alignof *T != alignof T or alignof (*T)* != alignof T.

@WilliamRyman: How could they have abused the meaning of a pointer erroneously when they have said from the beginning that an HWND is not a pointer, but an opaque data structure? If they specifically tell you do not treat this as anything but an HWND, and you choose to treat it as a pointer (or anything else), how is this their fault?

@KenWhite They implemented HWND in the C source as a pointer. That means that per the operational semantics of the code, HWND is indeed a pointer. Pointers inherently have alignment. The alignment of the pointer the Windows team chose is 4 bytes. That means that the handle should also have an alignment of 4 bytes. Code has meaning, even if it's just C.

@KenWhite If the WinAPI team wanted handles to be identified with alignmentless pointers, why didn't they just define them as typedef struct { char unused; } *HANDLE;? Then handles would be alignmentless in the same sense as void * is.

@KenWhite Can't you agree that int *x = (int *) 3; is inherently bad C code? Even if you never actually use x as a pointer (i.e. dereference it)? Indirection by typedef is insubstantial.

@WilliamRyman I was referring to your statement:  "a code translator (from C to Zig) that interprets HWND as an aligned pointer". As stated, HWND is not a real pointer (same with other kinds of kernel handles), so such code is broken to begin with and really needs to be fixed.

@RemyLebeau Sorry, I'm a bit slow. I still don't see how "The alignment of a pointer is not guaranteed to be the same as the alignment of the thing it points at" relates to what I said about HWND being interpreted as a pointer.

HWND might look like a pointer, but it is just a unique identifier with the same number of bits as a pointer that the Win32 Subsystem can then use for internal handle table lookups. Do not trust that typedef that's defined in the header; it is just defining a structure pointer to make sure that it's not implicitly used with other data types. (ie, if it was just uintptr_t or PVOID or an equivalent typedef, then it's difficult to differentiate a set of functions expecting the argument to be a window handle with another set of functions also using uintptr_t for something completely different like a bitmap or icon handle).
Browsing through the source code for ReactOS (starting from the NtUserCreateWindowEx function) indicates that the returned handle is just a handle table index shifted left by one bit (likely for legacy 16-bit compatibility, as you mentioned) and added to some pre-calculated constant base value. This doesn't necessarily mean that this is what is actually being used by the official Win32 sources, but it may give you an idea about how it may be working internally (given that ReactOS attempts to implement a binary compatible operating system for both user mode and kernel mode).
EDIT: As mentioned in the comments by user IInspectable, Raymond Chen has published two articles relating to this: How are window manager handles determined in 16-bit Windows and Windows 95? and the follow-up: How are window manager handles determined in Windows NT?

Thanks for the response. It kinda sucks that Windows chose to set things up this way rather than just have integral handles. It's causing some problems for me with FFI.

Actually when you use C or C++ with official Windows headers, the choice is yours and has always been for more than 30 years: you can force all HANDLE types like HWND to be void* if you disable STRICT https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog/disabling-strict . Of course we rarely do this since we have generally no reason to do so.

A bit of historical background as to why the handle is multiplied by two and gets added a value: How are window manager handles determined in Windows NT? (this is a follow-up to How are window manager handles determined in 16-bit Windows and Windows 95?).

@SimonMourier Thanks for the comment. I did see that this was possible when I looked in <windef.h> (my "abridging" was effectively just removing the #ifdef). But is there really no way to have the code function correctly (or in C's case behave semantically correctly) other than by just removing all type safety?

@WilliamRyman - I don't see how but if you're after code generation/translation you don't really care about C/C++ compilation-time type safety, do you

@SimonMourier The language I'm using is Zig which has superb interop with C, but this means that Zig types are effectively just C's when translating, but have stronger assertions (that you might like to enforce in C, but can't). So in this particular case, I actually do care because extern void * != extern T *, even when translated into Zig. I could just manually edit the translated files, but I want to keep my codebase mixed (C/Zig). To me editing the files would be akin to compiling a C source, editing the machine code, and distributing the source with a comment.

@WilliamRyman For what it's worth, windows-sys (the Rust FFI bindings for the Win32 API) uses isize to represent all handle types. It is guaranteed to be layout-compatible with void*. Does Zig provide similar ABI guarantees?

@IInspectable AFAIK, Zig's usize/isize are basically the same as C's (u)intptr_t types, e.g. pointer types are trivially castable to usize and vice versa. BTW, I ended up using NO_STRICT as @SimonMourier suggested.
